# What is HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, kernel, driver, hid

What is `HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR` and what is the use of this. I had found some definitions in web, but I don't understand. How we can use use this and how we can edit a Report Descriptor.
Please guide me, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This](http://frank.circleofcurrent.com/cache/hid_tutorial_1.htm)** tutorial pretty much explains everything in detail about `HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR`.

Please do a google search before you ask a question.

Comment: What calls for this downvote? especially when the OP found it worth enough to be marked as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

A HID Report Descriptor is a description for a HID Report.  :-)

It describes what a Human Interface Device can do, and how you talk to it.

http://www.usblyzer.com/usb-human-interface-device-hid-class-decoder.htm